# autoplay after jump to currentTime in html5 video

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm trying to create a video that autoplays from a point in the video after you jump to it after clicking a button. I have it so that the video jumps to the spot, but I cannot figure out how to get it to autoplay from there.  I'm new to javascript and I think there might be a simple solution I'm missing.

```
    function Fwd(){
        if (video.currentTime < 17.91 && video.currentTime >= 0)
        { (video.currentTime = 17.92)
        }
        else if (video.currentTime < 35.93 && video.currentTime > 17.91)
        { (video.currentTime = 35.94)
        }
    }
```

> Here is some of my html

```
<div id="sideright">
  <input type="button" id="fwdButton" onclick="Fwd()" class="button_fwdrew" />
</div>

<video id="video" width="896" height="504" data-setup="{}" >
<source src="video/myAwesomeVideo.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
<source src="video/myAwesomeVideo.webmhd.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
<source src="video/myAwesomeVideo.oggtheora.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
<p>Your browser doesn't support HTML5. Maybe you should upgrade.</p>
</video>
```

> Here is more of my JavaScript

```
var v = document.getElementById("video")[0];
    v.volume = .5;
    v.pause();
    video.onpause = video.onplay = function(e) {
    playpause.value = video.paused ? 'Play' : 'Pause';
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't [`video.play()`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#playing-the-media-resource) work?

```
function Fwd(){
    var video = document.getElementById("video");
    if (video.currentTime < 17.91 && video.currentTime >= 0)
    { 
        (video.currentTime = 17.92)
    }
    else if (video.currentTime < 35.93 && video.currentTime > 17.91)
    { 
        (video.currentTime = 35.94)
    }
    video.play();
}
```

I've added a declaration for the `video` variable since this seems to be causing some confusion.

In your edit you have created a `v` variable but you've assigned to it the value of the first property or method of the DOM object associated with the element with `id` of `video` (that's what the array accessor `[0]` does after `document.getElementById("video")`).  Almost certainly that property or method won't itself have a property `volume` or a method `pause()`.  After that you've started using a `video` variable without apparently defining it or setting its value.  It may be defined in code you've not posted, but from what you've shown that would be a waste since you're apparently trying to make the `v` variable be the reference to the video element - there's no need for both `v` and `video`.

Decide on one variable to hold your reference to the video element, assign it using `document.getElementById("video")` and then use it consistently.

Comment: Hi robertc, thanks for your reply, but unfortunately the video still doesn't play.

Comment: @Noob_C The post more of your code, or a link to your example.

Comment: I added some more code above, let me know if you need more.  I'm not really sure what would be useful.  I have quite alot of JS and html that are unrelated to this issue that control volume, muting, etc...

Comment: @Noob_C OK, where are you setting the `video` variable?

Comment: I added some more Javascript.  Maybe the video variable is the problem because I know the v.volume = .5; isn't working

Comment: I'm really confused.  I changed my var v to var video (and got rid of [0]) and now nothing works.  I have nothing else that references var v, but now my play/pause buttons don't work.  Adding the video.play(); at the end of the function Fwd doesn't make the video autoplay either.  Thanks for your help but I might find someone to look at all my code in person.

Comment: @Noob_C Try uploading it somewhere, then we could all look.

Comment: Your answer is correct.  It turns out I had some conflicting JavaScript.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
var update = function() {
    if (document.getElementById("video").currentTime < 10) 
    {
        document.getElementById("video").currentTime = 10;
    }
};
document.getElementById("video").setAttribute("ontimeupdate", "update();");
document.getElementById("video").play();
```